# Memory-leaks with ICreateDevEnum, IEnumMoniker, BindToStorage

Tags: c++, windows, memory-leaks, com

When executing the following code, extracted from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407292%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), there is some serious memory leaks. I am using mingw 5.3 (same leaks with mingw 4.8) and Windows 7.

Did I forget to call a Release() or another method to prevent the leak ?

```
#include <dshow.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <mmdeviceapi.h>
#include <uuids.h>

void print_device() {
  // Create the System Device Enumerator.
  HRESULT hr;
  ICreateDevEnum *pSysDevEnum = NULL;
  hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SystemDeviceEnum, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
      IID_ICreateDevEnum, (void **)&pSysDevEnum);
  if (FAILED(hr))
  {
      return;
  }

  // Obtain a class enumerator for the video compressor category.
  IEnumMoniker *pEnumCat = NULL;
  hr = pSysDevEnum->CreateClassEnumerator(CLSID_VideoCompressorCategory, &pEnumCat, 0);

  if (hr == S_OK)
  {
      // Enumerate the monikers.
      IMoniker *pMoniker = NULL;
      ULONG cFetched;
      while(pEnumCat->Next(1, &pMoniker, &cFetched) == S_OK)
      {
          IPropertyBag *pPropBag;
          hr = pMoniker->BindToStorage(0, 0, IID_IPropertyBag,
              (void **)&pPropBag);
          if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
          {
              // To retrieve the filter's friendly name, do the following:
              VARIANT varName;
              VariantInit(&varName);
              hr = pPropBag->Read(L"FriendlyName", &varName, 0);
              if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
              {
                std::wcout << varName.bstrVal << '\n';
              }
              VariantClear(&varName);
          }
          pMoniker->Release();
      }
      pEnumCat->Release();
  }
  pSysDevEnum->Release();
}

int main() {
  // Initializes
  CoInitialize( NULL );

  // loop to test leak    
  while( true ) {
    print_device();
  }
}
```

Comment: At first glance it seems you are missing a release call for the pPropBag variable.
I would suggest using smart com pointers that remove the need to manually call AddRef and Release.

Comment: I added pPropBag->Release() and there is no more leak. Thank you.